# Re-add a removed company page?

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

I accidentally removed a Company Page from my privacy settings. Is it possible to re-add the Company Page without requesting a re-invitation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually no, but I just reverted your revoked permission manually and you should be good to go.

Comment: +1 for answering the question and thanks for fixing it for me :)